# Only include in where condition if date is not low date(01/01/0001)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq

I have a query that has a where condition to check and find addresses that were added after a certain date. The date field is not required so I want Date field in where condition to be only considered if it is not 1/1/0001.
dtmDate is the parameter that is being passed

Query

```
from b in _context.customer
           join d in _context.Address on b.id equals d.Id 
           join e in _context.units on d.Id equals e.Id
           where (req.dtmDate.Year != 1 && d.DateAdded >= req.dtmDate)

select new modelAddress
              {
               address= d.address
              }
```

But this is not working. It is not returning any rows

Comment: Where is `req` defined?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it is a model that has a property dtmDate which is being passed in this function

Comment: Most likely because `req.dtmDate` is set to the default value, and your `where` clause is specifying that records should only be returned if `req.dtmDate.Year != 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a `DateTime` object called `req.dtmDate` that may be set to a default value, and you want to return all items where the item's `DateAdded` field is greater than `req.dtmDate`, unless `req.dtmDate` is `1/1/0001`, in which case all records should be returned.

If that's the case, I think you could just modify your existing code to:

```
where (req.dtmDate.Year == 1 || d.DateAdded >= req.dtmDate)
```

Comment: How about req.dtmDate == DateTime.MinValue  instead of  req.dtmDate.Year == 1 ?

Comment: Also, you should check `req.dtmDate.Year != 1`  before doing the query.. Shouldnt be part of the `WHERE`

Answer (score 2):

I'd leverage the fact that LINQ queries are not executed when you write them, so you can add clauses conditionally after you've created a base query:

```
var query = from b in _context.customer
       join d in _context.Address on b.id equals d.Id 
       join e in _context.units on d.Id equals e.Id;

if(req.dtmDate.Year != 1)
  query = query.Where(d.DateAdded >= req.dtmDate);

var result = query.Select(
  new modelAddress
  {
    address= d.address
  }
);
```

I prefer this because I've previously run into issues, particularly with EF LINQ queries when the Where clause contains something that evaluates to true locally with in the code, rather than as something the DB will evaluate. It seems to work out better when "wildcarding" DB queries, to use a pattern of "if x is true then add-another-where-clause" rather than saying "where(local-value-of-x-equals-local-constant OR some-db-data-value-equals-y)"

Comment: This really is a better approach, and for the same reason.  I've had numerous queries go haywire (poor query plan caching) because of using the approach mentioned by Rufus.  Your approach will generate different queries (and therefore different query plans) based on whether the dtmDate should be considered as part of the query, and will always use the best query plan for each.